# ActsAsTaggableOn add tag to object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, acts-as-taggable-on

I'm working on a legacy project that uses ActsAsTaggableOn, but it looks (based on the documentation) that it isn't using it normally?

my Reports object has several ActsAsTaggableOn objects, year_tags, for example.

I'm trying to add a tag, and based on: https://rubydoc.info/gems/acts-as-taggable-on/#usage I should be able to just use :

```
report.year_tags.add("foo")
```

However, that says:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `add' for #<ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007fbedb9134e8>
```

I can list  `year_tags` and get the length, and when I output them, I get strings as expected (printed one per line, but maybe that's normal for Ruby?)

I year_tags DOES have a `push` method but that wants an `ActsAsTaggableOn` object, not a string... which seems weird.

ETA:

a bit more detail, having spent more time looking at this:

It appears that the typical way of using `ActsAsTaggableOn` is to have a single tag_list, however, we have several distinct types of tags, so we have `report.year_tags`, and `report.level_tags`, etc... Each one appears to be a, maybe iterator? on a list of `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag` objects? or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use acts_as_taggable_on
e.g. `acts_as_taggable_on :year_tags`
then you'll be able to do `year_tags_list.add "tag"`
[see source code as reference](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/6055f9618a004c5bfdf1740d5479f4885696b7ee/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/taggable.rb#L39)

Comment: This is probably what you were saying, but: report.year_tag_list.add("bar") works. thanks! (also need report.save at the end. That is probably obvious to everyone but me...)